# blank area in DataWindow margin

Tags: powerbuilder

I have tabular DataWindow in my window:

[image: opt_IMG_20130620_092903.jpg]

Then i have code that doing it:
[image: opt_IMG_20130620_092932.jpg]
(qwe is the middle column.
 asd is the right column)

The problem is I don't know how fix the blank 
area:
[image: opt_IMG_20130620_092919.jpg]

Thanks!

Comment: why posting a *picture* of your code when you could just copy /paste it in the question o_O ?

Comment: Im develope in sepereate enviorment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke i found solution.
PowerBuilder calculate the the biggest sum of X+Width (when its expression, default value consider) from all columns (Include invisible).
The calculation performed after Create method of UO DataWindow.

Amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

i like your screenshoots, they look like real :) So I think your problem is that there are INVISIBLE columns on your datawindow. Thats why the width is larger than you expected. You can do two things:

- remove the invisible controls from your datawindow (just delete it. you do not need to delete these fields from the select)
- set the width to 0 for the invisible columns

I hope this helps!

Regards
Gábor

Ps.: I forget to say that you need to set the LABEL and COLUMNS width also to 0 (or delet BOTH of that)

Comment: Hey do you know how deleting columns?

Comment: Hi, simply open the datawindow and select the columns control AND label. delete both of them